# Align asp:Button above first column of the gridview below

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I have a styling problem

I am trying to align a button with the first column of a gridview which is right underneath.

Something like this:

[image: Something like this]

I've done the following but obviously it will fail with different resolutions:

```
<div class="formsFormBlock">
     <asp:Label ID="LblRecurError" runat="server" />
     <div style="text-align: left; position: relative; left: -15%;">
          <table style="border: 0">
               <tr>
                    <td style="border: 0">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnRecur" runat="server" Text="Repeat" />
                    </td>
               </tr>
          </table>
    </div>
<asp:GridView>
</asp:GridView>
```

How can i do this?

Addition:

the gridview doesn't have a cssclass but the div above has the following css attributes:

```
.formsFormBlock{clear:both;position:relative;border-bottom:1px solid #e8f1f7;padding:0.53em 0.83em}
.formsFormBlock .formsItemLabel{display:block;width:25%;float:left;position:relative}
.formsFormBlock .formsItemLabel em{position:absolute;/*right:1.66em*/color:#ff0000}
.formsFormBlock .formsFormBlockHint{color:#999;font-size:92%;}

#formsFormHd:after, .formsFormBlock:after{content:".";display:block;height:0;clear:both;visibility:hidden;}
#formsFormHd, .formsFormBlock{display:block;clear:both;}
*:first-child+html #formsFormHd, *:first-child+html .formsFormBlock{display:inline-block;}
```

Comment: Ok I solved it but i wish for a better solution.
Mine was just putting the gridview in a <tr> underneath the button.

Comment: What about putting the `<asp:Button />` **just** before your `<asp:GridView>`?

Comment: I did that but it resulted in button on the far left and GV in the middle of the page.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<div class="formsFormBlock">
     <div style="text-align: left; position: relative; left: -15%;">
          <table style="border: 0">
               <tr>
                    <td style="border: 0">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnRecur" runat="server" Text="Repeat" />
                         <asp:Label ID="LblRecurError" runat="server" />
                    </td>
               </tr>
          </table>
    </div>
<asp:GridView>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   <div id="container">
        <div style="float: left; margin-bottom: 10px;">
            <asp:Label ID="LblRecurError" runat="server" />
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="btnRecur" runat="server" Text="Repeat" />
        </div>
        <div style="clear: left;">
            <asp:GridView runat="server">
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
    </div>
```

cheers